# How to properly convert QList<QNetworkCookie> to QByteArray?

Tags: c++, qt

there is a function in Qt `QList<QNetworkCookie> QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(const QByteArray & cookieString)` to convert `QByteArray` into `QList<QNetworkCookie>`, however, how can I properly do the reserved conversion?

I've tried using QVariant with:

```
QVariant v;
v.setValue(cookies); // cookies has type of QList<QNetworkCookie>
QByteArray bytes = v.toByteArray();
```

But in fact I got empty `bytes` in this way.

So I rolled my own ones:

```
inline QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &d, const QList<QNetworkCookie> &c)
{
    QList<QByteArray> l;
    for(auto const & cookie: c) {
        l << cookie.toRawForm();
    }
    return d << l;
}

inline QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &d, QList<QNetworkCookie> &c)
{
    QList<QByteArray> l;
    d >> l;
    for(auto const & bytes: l) {
        c += QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(bytes);
    }
    return d;
}
```

<del>However, the `QList<QNetworkCookie>` I got cannot be recognized by `setCookiesFromUrl`, which always returns false.</del>

So how to properly convert `QList<QNetworkCookie>` to `QByteArray`?

p.s. I'm using Qt 5.3 now.

**UPDATE:**

**The second way above is properly working. I made a mistake on cookie's domain.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```
QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies; // Your cookies list
QByteArray data;               // Converted data

foreach (QNetworkCookie c, cookies) {
    data.append(c.toRawForm());
    data.append(';');
}
```

Comment: `QNetworkCookie::parseCookies` seems not working on this. In fact I found I made a mistake on cookies domain. See my update.